# PyDub - [WinError 6] The handle is invalid, while using AudioSegment.from_file

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-3.7, pydub

I want to convert an audio file from one format to another, so I used Pydub AudioSegment.

```
AudioSegment.from_file(input_filename, 'mp4')
```

The python script file runs perfectly, but when I bundle it as an executable using pyinstaller, I get the following error.

I read through Github issue pages and implemented the solutions suggested there, but that doesn't seem to work. I have placed the ffmpeg.exe and ffprobe.exe in my project directory and set the path using AudioSegment.converter

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "main.py", line 91, in change_format
        converted_audio = AudioSegment.from_file(input_filename, 'mp4')
      File "lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 685, in from_file
      File "lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 274, in mediainfo_json
      File "subprocess.py", line 728, in __init__
      File "subprocess.py", line 1025, in _get_handles
    OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

Please suggest ways to fix this.

Comment: `procmon` from sysinternals might provide you with some useful information

Comment: how do you run the executable file? Are you redirecting its output? Also, which windows version are you on? This looks like a Windows issue.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: you can edit the subprocess call per this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43004804/8742968